# How to filter coloums with no value in grid?

Tags: attributes, collection, grid, filter, dropdown-attribute

In Store>Manage Grid , I have added a "empty" value to drop downs which filters out all the records in which this particular field is empty. It works fine for all but is having problems for those drop downs whose back-end type is int.Please 
do Suggest some solution for it.

```
// I am adding this only to dropdowns:
    $selectValues["None"] = "-empty-";                 
                $this->addColumn($attribute->getAttributeCode(), array(
                    'header' => $attribute->getFrontendLabel(),
                    'type' => 'options',
                    'index' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
                    'type' => 'options',
                    'options' => $selectValues,
                    'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterEmpty')
                ));
```

and I am fitering out these as follows

```
protected function _FilterEmpty($collection, $column) {

    $value = $column->getFilter()->getValue();
    $columnName = $column->getId();


        if (!($value = $column->getFilter()->getValue())) {
            return;
        }
        else if ($value == "None")
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($columnName, array('null' => true));
        else
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($columnName, $value);  

    return $this;
}
```

But problem here is that, those attributes which are having backend type as int don't have a null value(as default). So what should I do with these  to filter out thoes coloums in which we don't hava a value.

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Can you explain how exactly you did this and what problems you are facing?

Comment: Thanks @FabianSchmengler , I have added code here, may you have better understanding now.

Comment: What is the default value in case your backend type is int?

Comment: there is no record in case of int. (i.e record will be created only when there is a value).